# jq returning full result after operation

Tags: jq

I'm adding a property to a JSON string with

```
result=$(jq -c ".docs[$docIndex] + { \"value\": \"value\" }"<<<"$fileContent")
```

Where the JSON inside `$fileContent` is

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "id": 123
        },
        {
            "id": 456
        },
        {
            "id": 678
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

But what is inside `$result`after my operation is `{"id:123", "value":"value"}`. How do I return the full output? What I would like is that result becomes

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "value": "value"
        },
        {
            "id": 456
        },
        {
            "id": 678
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you try to use `+=` instead of `+`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jq is fundamentally a filter, so `.docs[0]` limits the data that the rest of the script has available to what it selected. At the end of the program, whatever's in the stream is outputted. Thus the `+ { ... }` only sees the one object, and its output is used as the output of the whole program.

If instead you want to *modify* one of the elements you've selected, [use `+=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Arithmeticupdate-assignment:+=,-=,*=,/=,%25=,//=), which is an alias for the [update-assignment operator `|= . + ...`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=):

```
jq '.docs[1] += { "value": "value" }' < ...
```

You could equivalently write the desugared

```
jq '.docs[1] |= . + { "value": "value" }' < ...
```

In either case, it replaces the current value (what `.` was when you started) with the result of applying the change you describe to the element(s) you selected. That new value carries on through the pipeline, in this case immediately to the output stage.